# How to block outgoing OpenVPN connections on CentOS 7 with firewalld?

Tags: linux, openvpn, firewalld

There are:

- 192.168.1.0/24 network (gateway 192.168.1.1) with access to the Internet (IP: 345.45.67.89)
- OpenVPN server (CentOS 7) connected via `eth0` (192.168.1.2) (OpenVPN port: 1194 | `tun0` 10.8.0.0/24 network)
- Forward rule at gateway 192.168.1.1 from 345.45.67.89:54321 to 192.168.1.2:1194

Need to block 192.168.1.5 for visiting it by OpenVPN clients.

I'm trying to add rule:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 192.168.1.5 -j DROP
```

Via ssh at server `curl http://192.168.1.5 -o out` is 0%. But via OpenVPN I have access to the http://192.168.1.5.

`tun0` in trusted with enabled masquarade. Looks like problem with it.

What rules should I use for DROP outgoing connections to 192.168.1.5 from 10.8.0.0/24?

**ifconfig**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 XXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether XXX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1176345  bytes 119424262 (113.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23934  bytes 17136251 (16.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 344 (344.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 344 (344.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        inet6 XXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 11947  bytes 904082 (882.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15492  bytes 15376868 (14.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones**

```
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: openvpn ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: tun0
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

**sudo firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules**

```
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 192.168.1.5 -j DROP
```